# Simple android app not compiling following tutorial

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm following the android tutorial online here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

To make apps and the `activity_my.xml` file contains this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But the app will not compile with two errors:

> Error:(18, 54) error: cannot find symbol variable toolbar
>
> Error:(21, 76) error: cannot find symbol variable fab

Before I edited my activity.xml file it contained this code which I replaced with the LinearLayout block like it said in the tutorial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MyActivity" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?  attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_my" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can someone point out the problem and also are the `content.xml` and `activity.xml` files supposed to have the same code?

EDIT:
Here is the java code of MyActivity (I haven't touched it since I started the tutorial)

```
package com.example.marcel.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Which version of appcompact are you using?

Comment: Just added the java file. What is AppCompact?

Comment: What type of errors u get in logcat?
You can also create a sample application by creating a new application. It will show some sample apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is trying to get the FloatingActionButton fab, and the toolbar, Remove the code or include this in the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?  attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</LinearLayout>
```

or use this java code

```
package com.example.marcel.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried putting it in but Android Studio says multiple root tags? Do I add it in below the LinearLayout block?

Comment: Those two bits of code were originally in the activity xml but the tutorial that I linked above said it should instead have the LinearLayout?

Comment: Post your java code, it will be easy to guide you, anyway I updated my answer to give you the full code ( but it wont see as you want to see it, it may change the design you want)

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: Thanks that works, but do you know why my activity.xml originally had that "coordinator layout" code instead of the "linear layout" code like in the tutorial?

Comment: yes, that is because the sample app have a Toolbar and a floating button, I just remove them to make it work( also I removed the AppCompatActivity to make things easy for you), I recommend you to start from basic and then search tutorial of how to add a toolbar, or a floating button

Comment: coordinator layout is a more complex layout, that collapse items when scrolling, When you create an activity, you can choose between a lot of "start points" you just simply choose a template with toolbar and floating button , use Empty activity instead

Answer (score 0):

your activity class has remained references of `fab button` and `toolbar`. Remove both of this from your activity class. clean project and then run again..